# При подключении скрипта js ошибка 400

Tags: http-status-code-400

В теле страницы подключаю скрипт

```
<script src="http://site.ru/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

в консоли при этом ошибка 400 Bad request ((

Скрипт по этому url существует!
Пытаюсь напрямую открыть этот файл в браузере, пишет: Неверный запрос ((

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Причину нашел, устранил, но не ло конца понял суть.
Рядом с этим файлом был одноименный архив .gz
удалил, всё стало нормально подцепляться